# Android "mediaplayer" one instance

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the player. How can I make it so that only one instance of the player can run?
I need this because the stop function is not working.

```java
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    Context mContext;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void native_player(int action, String streamurl) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (action == 1) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamurl);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
                mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

I tried to look for a solution on the Internet, but was unable to fix it myself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The is how we create single instance

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayerInstance(){

if(mediaPlayer == null){
return mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
else return mediaPlayer;

}
```

how to use is simple

```
mediaPlayer = getMediaPlayerInstance()
```